# React-Native app is crashing in some Android phones

Tags: android, react-native

My React-Native app is crashing in some Samsung devices which has **OS version 9**. It is working fine in all other devices. Application's React-Native version is **0.57.5**. Here I am uploading a screenshots. For **Samsung Exynos 7870**, which is working fine and For **Samsung A30**, in which I am getting crash issue.

[image]

Here is the scenario: I installed the app, Splash screen is launched and then it is crashing.

**Android studio crash log:**

```
2019-11-04 15:35:28.451 13820-14072/com.openchair E/SoLoader: Error when loading lib: dlopen failed: "/data/data/com.openchair/lib-main/libgnustl_shared.so" is 32-bit instead of 64-bit lib hash: 38a149cf3f94c06f35444ea1c5280541 search path is /data/app/com.openchair-RKWR45KUxyRawC30KCnIFQ==/lib/arm64
2019-11-04 15:35:28.451 13820-14072/com.openchair E/SoLoader: couldn't find DSO to load: libgnustl_shared.so caused by: dlopen failed: "/data/data/com.openchair/lib-main/libgnustl_shared.so" is 32-bit instead of 64-bit
2019-11-04 15:35:28.451 13820-14072/com.openchair E/SoLoader: couldn't find DSO to load: libglog.so caused by: couldn't find DSO to load: libgnustl_shared.so caused by: dlopen failed: "/data/data/com.openchair/lib-main/libgnustl_shared.so" is 32-bit instead of 64-bit
2019-11-04 15:35:28.452 13820-14072/com.openchair E/SoLoader: couldn't find DSO to load: libglog_init.so caused by: couldn't find DSO to load: libglog.so caused by: couldn't find DSO to load: libgnustl_shared.so caused by: dlopen failed: "/data/data/com.openchair/lib-main/libgnustl_shared.so" is 32-bit instead of 64-bit
2019-11-04 15:35:28.452 13820-14072/com.openchair E/SoLoader: couldn't find DSO to load: libreactnativejni.so caused by: couldn't find DSO to load: libglog_init.so caused by: couldn't find DSO to load: libglog.so caused by: couldn't find DSO to load: libgnustl_shared.so caused by: dlopen failed: "/data/data/com.openchair/lib-main/libgnustl_shared.so" is 32-bit instead of 64-bit
2019-11-04 15:35:28.453 13820-14072/com.openchair E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-8
    Process: com.openchair, PID: 13820
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: couldn't find DSO to load: libreactnativejni.so caused by: couldn't find DSO to load: libglog_init.so caused by: couldn't find DSO to load: libglog.so caused by: couldn't find DSO to load: libgnustl_shared.so caused by: dlopen failed: "/data/data/com.openchair/lib-main/libgnustl_shared.so" is 32-bit instead of 64-bit
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.doLoadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:703)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoName(SoLoader.java:564)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:500)
        at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary(SoLoader.java:455)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.ReactBridge.staticInit(ReactBridge.java:18)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeMap.<clinit>(NativeMap.java:19)
        at com.facebook.react.bridge.JSCJavaScriptExecutorFactory.create(JSCJavaScriptExecutorFactory.java:21)
        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:917)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Can you please help me with this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you check this? https://github.com/a-tarasyuk/create-rx-app/issues/12

Comment: Yes I checked and try with `ndk {  
    abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"  
}` but it will not allowed when I upload the build on Play store

Comment: umm, okay. have never faced this issue, lemme check once

Comment: 64-bit support is only available in react-native 0.59 and above. can you try upgrading it and see if it helps?